# Right form of the grammar

Tags: grammar, verbs, complex-sentences

I'm having doubt in using these structures, meaning when to use one over the other...

Reading books helps me in enhancing my knowledge.

Vs

Reading books helps me to enhance my knowledge.

Comment: You can use either; they are both grammatical. It's a matter of style and personal preference. Just like you could also say *in the enhancement of my knowledge* or *helps me achieve enhanced knowledge*.

Comment: @JasonBassford Grammar is a matter of syntax and semantics. The semantics are not just a matter of personal preferences or style! The syntax is not obviously green sheep sleeping furiously. But it's still very bad grammar because it's bad style to involve so many levels of indirection and redundancy to lead to these seemingly equivalent phrases. ugh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both perfectly appropriate to use, they are simply different forms. It depends on one's personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct and there is not much difference  in meaning.It is just a matter  of  choice.